# Regex For HTML Name Attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex script that will parse through HTML name attributes and return each nested array as a match. Here's an example:

```
<input type="text" name="contact[email]" />
<input type="text" name="contact[address][street]" />
```

I need some javascript regex that will parse those and match them in this way

```
Match 1: contact Match 2: email
Match 1: contact Match 2: address Match 3: street
```

Here's the current regex I have:

```
/(^.*?)(\[(.*?)\])?$/
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your regex engine or environment?

Comment: Are you using the regex on the `name` attribute or on the entire string of  HTML?

Comment: @Jerry it is Javascript

Comment: @Explosion Pills I'm using it solely on the name attribute.

Comment: where does the source text come from? innerHTML? String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is

```
var str = "contact[email]"
str.match(/\w+/g)
//=> ["contact", "email"]

var str = "contact[address][street]"
str.match(/\w+/g)
//=> ["contact", "address", "street"]
```

Comment: Yes you're right this turned out to make things so much simpler!

Comment: Nice answer! I'm just curious though. Will the spots that say "address" or "email" have an actual address/email or will it be just the word? If it's just the word then you're all set, but if you need to capture an actual email then this will not work.

Comment: @Th3BFG, the output is exactly as displayed in my post. My code does nothing to read the `value` attribute of the `INPUT` element.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm not sure why I was thinking the name would have an email address.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is delimit each of your `name` with `[]`
So it would go like this:

```
<input type="text" name="[contact][email]" />
<input type="text" name="[contact][address][street]" />
```

Then I would use this for the regex:

```
(?:\[)(.*?)(?:\])
```

My solution cuts down on the number of operations needed and makes your naming convention a lot more straight forward. Each match would represent a separate entry in the `name` section

Comment: Oh, and if your regex engine requires it, use this:
`^(?:\[)(.*?)(?:\])$`

Comment: I think your regex engine would want this:
`/(?:\[)(.*?)(?:\])$/g`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
/(^[^\[]+)(?=\[)|(([^\[\]]+)(?=\]))/g
```

Example usage below.

[**Demo fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/zsNX9/2)

HTML:

```
<input id="one" type="text" name="contact[email]" />
<input id="two" type="text" name="contact[address][street]" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var regex = /(^[^\[]+)(?=\[)|(([^\[\]]+)(?=\]))/g;

var nameOne = document.getElementById('one').getAttribute('name');
console.log('one: ', nameOne.match(regex));
var nameTwo = document.getElementById('two').name;
console.log('two: ',nameTwo.match(regex));
```

Output:

```
one: ["contact", "email"]
two: ["contact", "address", "street"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="(?<type>[A-Za-z0-9]+)" name="(?<Name>[A-Za-z0-9\[\]]+)" />
```

works fine. I attached Image to show how works

[image]

as each value will be returned in array after RegexMatch, 
then you can do this

```
var first = RegexMatch.Groups["Name"].Split('[')[0];
```

You will get the first value in the `name="contact[address][street]"`, first = "contact"
then you can do

```
var second = regexMatch.Groups["Name"].Split('[')[1];
then second = "address";
```

by the way this is for C#, convert to javascript!!

Answer (score 0):

i like to use split() to grab middle-chunks instead of more complex RegExps:

```
var strFormHTML='<input type="text" name="contact[email]" /><input type="text" name="contact[address][street]" />';
var names = strFormHTML.split(/[\W\w]+? name=\"([^"]+)\"[\w\W]+?/).filter(Boolean).slice(0,-1); 
alert(names); //shows: "contact[email]", "contact[address][street]"
```